# How to remove a Label and Entry with a switch in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to remove Label Downpayment and Entry Downpayment with x:Name="MS" switch and also, change text/value of the Entry to "0". here is my  *.xaml code

'''

```
   <Label Text="Purchased price"
            Margin="0,100,0,0" Padding="13,0,0,0" />
    <Entry Placeholder="Price $$"
           x:Name="price"
           Keyboard="Numeric"
           Margin="130,-30,40,0"
           Opacity="1" Rotation="0"
           TranslationX="16" />

    <Label  Text="Mortgage ??"
            Margin="0,10,0,0" Padding="13,0,0,0"/>
    <Switch IsToggled="false"
            Margin="130,-30,40,0"
            x:Name="MS"/>


    <Label Text="Downpayment"
           Margin="0,10,0,0" Padding="13,0,0,0"/>
    <Entry Placeholder="Down Payment"
           x:Name="Downpayment"
           Text="DP"
           Keyboard="Numeric"
           Margin="130,-30,40,0"
           Opacity="1" Rotation="0"
           TranslationX="16" />
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a handler for the `Toggled` event

```
<Switch IsToggled="false" Toggled="SwitchToggled" ... />
```

then

```
protected void SwitchToggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
{
  // true if toggled
  if (e.Value)
  {
    Downpayment.IsVisible = false;
    DownpaymentLabel.IsVisible = false;
    price.Text = "0";
  }
}
```

Comment: Just need to add x:Name= "DownpaymentLabel" to the label. Thank you.